# Schedule display, layout time and week

Tags: java, android, calendar, schedule

I need to make a schedule on which day and at what time the tablet display will be turned on. How to write logic, I know. But I have another question. Perhaps there is a ready layout where, for example, the top will be written vrom time (00 01 02 03 ... 13 14 .. 23) and on the left there will be a column of the week (Monday, Monday, Wednesday .... Sunday). For example, for a calendar there is a CalendarViev. Is there a ready layout where will there be time and day? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean TimePicker and DatePicker?

Comment: @Domin Yes, but without a date. Only day of the week and time

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by this library - https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

```
<com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
    android:id="@+id/weekView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:textSize="12sp"
    app:hourHeight="60dp"
    app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
    app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
    app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
    app:columnGap="8dp"
    app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
    app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
    app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
    app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
    app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"/>
```